# Battery is fully charged but when I unplug my laptop it shows battery is low

Tags: 12.04, dell, battery

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on my dell INSPIRON N5110. 
The battery icon shows the battery is fully charged(when plugged). When I unplug it says that I have low battery and approximately 20 minutes of usage. Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Usually a laptop battery is composed of few battery cells. Same way, your battery will be made of some battery cells. Few of those cells might be dead now. That is the problem.

To make you much more clear, I can say like this. Lets say that your battery have 6 battery cells in it. When you bought it, all the 6 cells would have been alive. So it would have taken much time to get 100% charged. As well, it would have been taken more time to give a low battery warning. Lets say that 4 of your battery cells are damaged now. So your battery just have 2 live cells. Now, a very less time is enough to get your 2-cell-battery charged completely. Since it is a 2-cell-battery it drains much faster than your original-undamaged-battery. Hope you have got some knowledge about your battery. To know a bid more about battery-tech look [here](http://www.batteryeducation.com/2008/10/how-many-cells-are-in-a-battery.html).

**Possible Solutions:**

1. Buy a new battery.
2. Look through this [link](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-restore-a-dead-or-dying-laptop-battery/) and try to restore your dying battery.